# Building JavaFX application as Singleton

Tags: javafx

I have JavaFX application built and used as desktop app with an installer which created a shortcut on desktop. It works perfectly fine, but whenever clicks on shortcut, it opens a new window. I want to make changes to the app to act as singleton and open the same window if it is already opened.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Each time you launch your application, you are creating another JVM. So what you want is  a way to ensure that, at most, only one JVM of your application is running. So you need a way to find the running JVMs. One way is the [JPS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jps.html) utility. Its output includes the name of the class that you launched. You can run JPS from java code using class `ProcessBuilder`. Alternatively you could write an operating-system script, i.e. PowerShell for Windows or bash for linux, to launch your application which would first run JPS to see if the application wasn't already running.